# eclipse rcp :how to translate third-part plugin?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am working on a eclipse rcp application.it use some third-part plugins, how can I translate text in these plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general internationalization is easy in eclipse. You can look for *.properties files which contains the strings which are used in the plugin. You can then define an own property file with your translation.

If no property files exist the plugin is not foreseen to be translated. In this case code changes are necessary.

See [this howto](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Internationalization/how2I18n.html) for an example

Comment: addtion: When you define your own properties file, you create a fragment against the plugin you want to translate, and place the translated properties file in an equivalent location.